# Salesforce Lightning and the EmailAuthor

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, email

We want to switch from sfdc Classic to Lightning. But we are using a lot of custom fields with links (formula fields with hyperlinks) to refer to visualforce pages which are calling different apex functions. So far that does not pose a problem. But the return value of that functions are page references to either a object detail page (that works perfectly) or a page reference to the classic email author with predefined settings (contact, related object, email template, sender email, ...). This isn't working in Lightning.

How can we send certain emails (depending on the clicked button) in Lightning in the same way then in Classic with the good old EmailAuthor?